# Force ListView/BaseAdapter to inflate all needed views at the begining in android

Tags: android, listview, view, adapter, baseadapter

I have a rather expensive Layout that i inflate to a listview's childrens.
If the listview shows 5 childrens eatch time `getView()` will inflate only 5 (maybe one-two more) of my expensive Layouts. And then reuse it.
This process might take some time but it's ok.(It's at the same time i download data from the Internet so doesn't ruin the UX).

The problem is that if i scroll , at the beggining of the scrolling  one `convertView is null` so the listview needs to inflate one more time. This is happening only the first time i scroll. 
Is there any way to avoid that? Notice that i don't resize any of the children or the Listview. Is there a way to inflate that extra view at the beggining so i avoid the Scrolling Lag?

UPDATE
Also to be specific:

> My listview shows 3and a half rows .. Meaning 4.The adapter inflates 5. What the adapter whats to inflate another one? Maybe there is a more elegant solution to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a cache of views when your activity is started, or in your adapter's constructor? getView() could return views from this cache if any are available, or create its own as it normally would if no cached views are available.

(I would not recommend creating more than n+1 views, though, where n is the number of views you expect to have on the screen at any one time. And I **strongly** recommend against ever trying to recycle old views back into the cache!)

Comment: sounds like a good approach (more or less what i had in mind) But for this to be not hardcoded i have to calculate the number rows that the listview is going to show. Guess i have no helper class for this. (Need to calculate child height listview height and get the Number after that)

Comment: Also to be specific: My listview shows 3and a half rows .. Meaning 4.The adapter inflates 5. What the adapter whats to inflate another one? Maybe there is a more elegant solution to that